# Python extract whole content of column from data frame using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to extract the whole content of a column from a multi-column data frame using pandas but I am getting only a part of the column.

The code I am using is:

```
import pandas
import csv
data = pandas.read_csv('data1.csv', usecols = ['dbSNP RS ID'])

import sys  
sys.stdout = open("data2.csv", "w") 
print data
```

What I get is something like this:

```
       dbSNP RS ID
0        rs4147951
1        rs2022235
2        rs6425720
3       rs12997193
4        rs9933410
5        rs7142489
...            ...
934963  rs10262938
934964   rs6140985
934965   rs2704067
934966   rs2239441
934967  rs10041689

[934968 rows x 1 columns]
```

The first 2 lines of the csv file are:

```
"Probe Set ID","dbSNP RS ID","Chromosome","Physical Position","Strand","ChrX    pseudo-autosomal region 1","Cytoband","Flank","Allele A","Allele B","Associated Gene","Genetic Map","Microsatellite","Fragment Enzyme Type Length Start Stop","Allele Frequencies","Heterozygous Allele Frequencies","Number of individuals","In Hapmap","Strand Versus dbSNP","Copy Number Variation","Probe Count","ChrX pseudo-autosomal region 2","In Final List","Minor Allele","Minor Allele Frequency","% GC","OMIM"

"AFFX-   SNP_10000979","rs4147951","17","66943738","+","0","q24.2","GGATAAGGATGGGCTA[A/G]ATTATCATTGCTGTTA","A","G","ENST00000269080 // intron // 0 // Hs.58351 // ABCA8 // 10351 // ATP-binding cassette, sub-family A (ABC1), member 8 /// ENST00000428549 // intron // 0 // Hs.58351 // ABCA8 // 10351 // ATP-binding cassette, sub-family A (ABC1), member 8 /// ENST00000541225 // intron // 0 // Hs.58351 // ABCA8 // 10351 // ATP-binding cassette, sub-family A (ABC1), member 8 /// ENST00000542396 // intron // 0 // Hs.58351 // ABCA8 // 10351 // ATP-binding cassette, sub-family A (ABC1), member 8 /// NM_007168 // intron // 0 // Hs.58351 // ABCA8 // 10351 // ATP-binding cassette, sub-family A (ABC1), member 8","99.8510 // D17S795 // D17S2182 // --- // --- // deCODE /// 90.7912 // D17S1870 // D17S840 // AFM323TB1 // AFM207VF4 // Marshfield /// 82.3131 // --- // D17S1786 // 147671 // --- // SLM1","D17S795 // downstream // 265562 /// D17S1474E // upstream // 113179","NspI // ACATGT_ACATGT // 536 // 66943408 // 66943943 /// StyI // CCTTGG_CCATGG // 2334 // 66941614 // 66943947","0.3917 // 0.6083 // CEU /// 0.6444 // 0.3556 // CHB /// 0.6000 // 0.4000 // JPT /// 0.5667 // 0.4333 // YRI","0.3833 // CEU /// 0.4889 // CHB /// 0.4444 // JPT /// 0.5667 // YRI","60 // CEU /// 45 // CHB /// 45 // JPT /// 60 // YRI","YES","reverse","---","6","0","YES","A // CEU /// G // CHB /// G // JPT /// G // YRI","0.3917 // CEU /// 0.3556 // CHB /// 0.4000 // JPT /// 0.4333 // YRI","---","---"
```

Any idea about how to extract the 'dbSNP RS ID' from the 934968 rows??. Thank you very much !

Comment: what do the first couple of lines of your CSV look like?

Comment: IIUC do you want `data.values` ?

Comment: Hi @mirosval, I will edit the question and include the first two lines of the csv file

Comment: Hi @Fabio, some column values are strings, others are integers

Comment: Are you refering to the dots in the middle of your second code listing? If so it is just how pandas shows data, you don't want to print all of the 900k columns out... if you actually try to save them, they should all be there...

Comment: @Lucas actually I cannot understand "I am getting only a part of the column". Do you want the whole content of the "dbSNP RS ID" column as an array?

Comment: That's the problem, when I look at the output file (data2.csv) I see the same, and the file only weights 1 KB

Comment: the 934968 row is the row with index 934967 ...

Comment: @Fabio, what I mean is that I only get header values (30 values, e.g rs4147951) and tail values (30 values, e.g.  rs10041689) separated by "...", but I am not able to visualise the 900k values after saving the output file.

Comment: Yes @Colonel Beauvel, you are right

Comment: @Lucas try writing the file with the method posted in my answer.

Comment: @Fabio, it worked great !!. Thanks so much to you and the other guys !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you should read and write again a .csv file with:

```
data = pandas.read_csv('data1.csv', usecols = ['dbSNP RS ID'])

data.to_csv('data2.csv')
```

The problem with your code is that the `print` function actually writes on file only the part of the file that pandas shows in the terminal prompt. When there are too much rows it splits the output adding `...` in the middle.